# Completely remove KDE 5 from Debian

Tags: debian, kde, kde-plasma-5

I want to completely remove KDE 5 from my (Debian Unstable) system, including configuration files and my user configuration file. Is there a way to do it without reinstalling and/or creating a new user?

Comment: Have you looked at uninstalling it via the package manager?

Comment: Yes, but which package and with `apt-get` command to completely remove the packages and system configuration files? And  which configuration files on my home folder?

Comment: I was envisioning using Apper.  Search on kde.  Everything flagged as installed select to uninstall.  I'm not sure whether than would remove configuration files in your home folder, but they would be small, harmless files that would make no difference to leave behind.  Or, you could use a file manager (not sure what after KDE is removed, unless you install a different desktop), and search or browse the home tree for any subdirectories whose name contains "kde".  You could do the same thing from the command line.  Remove those subdirectories.

Comment: I just did a quick check, and that identifies some of the kde utilities, but not all.  e.g., it excludes the Calligra suite, Kate, Dolphin, k3b, kdiff3, knotes, basKet, digiKam, Ksnapshot, Okular, etc.  That bundle is massive.  Those will run on a system without kde, but many of them need things like libraries.  If you plan to keep the apps, you may need to reinstall them if dependencies are removed.  If you want to wipe everything with a kde fingerprint, you would probably need to get a full list and then do a similar search & remove, although they will likely be located mostly together.

Comment: Thanks. The issue here is that I have a very old Sid installation and the transition from KDE 4 to 5 and glibc botched it in several, albeit small, different ways. I wanted to remove all programs and keep a clean XFCE system, including removing the KDE config files, so I could start from scratch, but without reinstalling the entire system, as everything else besides KDE 5 is working fine.